# Java / MYSQL dispalying images from medium blob. java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set

Tags: java, mysql, image, blob, resultset

I am working on a java project which should display products from a MySQl epos database. 
The gui has two scrollable jpanels one for categories which is dynamically populated on startup with a button for each category and with a Jlabel, which displays (if present in the DB) an image from a medium blob field. 
The second scrollabe jpanel should react to a click of a button in the categories panel by extracting and loading a button displaying product names and a label displaying if present an image from medium blob for all products in that category.

MY categories panel loads fine with buttons and images, the problem is with the products panel which loads fine when I happen to select a category containing products without images but throws the following error when attempting to load products that do:

```
java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:855)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getBytes(ResultSetImpl.java:1923)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getBytes(ResultSetImpl.java:1917)
    at gapricing.app.first.GuiEvents.populateProducts(GuiEvents.java:103)
    at gapricing.app.first.GuiEvents.actionPerformed(GuiEvents.java:78)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

The sql query is made by the getProducts method of the DataLogic class shown below:

```
package gapricing.app.data;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;



public class DataLogic {

MySQLConnect mysqlConnect = new MySQLConnect();
private Connection connect = null;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

public ResultSet getCategories(){
    try {
 connect = mysqlConnect.connDatabase();    
 preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT image, name, texttip from CATEGORIES ORDER BY name");
 ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    return resultSet;
    } catch (Exception e){
    }
    return null;
}

public ResultSet getProducts(String catName){
    try {
 connect = mysqlConnect.connDatabase();    
 preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT IMAGE, NAME FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CATEGORY = (SELECT ID FROM CATEGORIES WHERE NAME = ?) ORDER BY NAME");
 preparedStatement.setString(1, catName);
 ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    return resultSet;
    } catch (Exception e){
    }
    return null;
}

 //close the resultSet
 public void close(){
 try {


 if (preparedStatement != null){
 preparedStatement.close();
 }

 if (connect != null){
 connect.close();
 }
 if (mysqlConnect != null){
 mysqlConnect.close();
 }
 } catch (Exception e){
 }
 }

}
```

This returns a ResultSet to the populateProducts() method of a class called GuiEvents the relevant section of which is:

```
public void populateProducts(String catName){
    ResultSet prodResults = null;
    prodResults = dataLogic.getProducts(catName);

    gui.prodList.removeAll();
    try{
    int count = 0;
    while (prodResults.next()) {
    ++count;   // Get data from the current row and use it
    } 

    prodResults.beforeFirst();

    GridLayout prodLayout = new GridLayout(count,2);
    gui.prodList.setLayout(prodLayout);

    while (prodResults.next()){
    System.out.println(prodResults.getString(2) + " , " + prodResults.getBytes(1));
    JButton prodBtn = new JButton();
    JLabel prodImgLabel = new JLabel();

     if (prodResults.getBytes(1) != null){
     prodImgLabel.setIcon(displayImage(results.getBytes(1)));
    }
    prodBtn.setText(prodResults.getString(2));
    prodImgLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    prodBtn.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.LEFT);
    prodBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
    prodBtn.setActionCommand(prodResults.getString(2));
    prodBtn.addActionListener(this);
    gui.prodList.add(prodImgLabel);
    gui.prodList.add(prodBtn);
    gui.prodList.updateUI();
}
} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
try{
prodResults.close();
} catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
dataLogic.close();
}
```

I'm quite new to java and the answer is probably staring me straight in the face. Other posts have seemed to suggest that it is an issue with closing db connections and resultsets, I am pretty sure I am doing so though. Can anyone help? thanks

Comment: In `displayImage(results.getBytes(1))` what is `results`? Do you mean `prodResults`?

Comment: Note that the stacktrace points you towards GuiEvents.java line 103.